# Plot line of a function in R

Tags: r, graph

I have the following script:

```
FGM = function (n,r,z){
  x = r*sqrt(n)/(2*z)
  Px = 1-pnorm(x)
}
re = 10000
data = data.frame(abs(rnorm(re,0,1)), abs(rnorm(re,0,1)), abs(rnorm(re,0,1)))
colnames(data) = c("n","r","z")
data$Px = FGM(data$n,data$r,data$z)
data$x = data$r*sqrt(data$n)/(2*data$z)

par(mar=c(4.5,4.5,1,1))
plot(data$x,data$Px, xlim = c(0,3), pch = 19, cex = 0.1, xaxs="i", yaxs="i",
     xlab = expression(paste("Standardized mutational size (",italic(x), ")")), 
     ylab = expression(paste("P"[a],"(",italic(x),")")))
```

[image]
Which is a recreation of the graph [found here (box 2)](http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v6/n2/pdf/nrg1523.pdf). You can see in this script that I do this by just plotting 10000 small black points with various values of n,z, and r. This seems like an ugly work around, I think I should just be able to give R my function

```
FGM = function (n,r,z){
  x = r*sqrt(n)/(2*z)
  Px = 1-pnorm(x)
  }
```

and have it plot a line on a graph. However, a few hours of scouring the web has been unproductive, and I tried a few ways with abline and lines but nothing worked, is there a way of doing it with these functions or another function?

Tried this...

```
plot(data$x,data$Px, xlim = c(0,3), ylim = c(0,0.5), xaxs="i", yaxs="i",
 xlab = expression(paste("Standardized mutational size (",italic(x), ")")), 
 ylab = expression(paste("P"[a],"(",italic(x),")")), type = "n")
curve(1-pnorm(r*sqrt(n)/(2*z)), add=T)
>Error in curve(1 - pnorm(r * sqrt(n)/(2 * z)), add = T) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
>
```

@PaulRegular offered this solution but it still plots based on data, not the formula itself. I'm looking for a solution which can produce the curve properly without large values of "re" - using the following but with "re" set to 10 you can see what I mean...

```
data <- data[order(data$x),]
lines(data$x, data$Px, lwd=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Many of us don't have a free access to this article.

Comment: running the script will show the same thing @pascal

Comment: Then remove the useless link.

Comment: Add the example graph you output from your script into your question yourself.

Comment: Your function is vectorised. No need for `mapply()`. Using `FGM( data$n,data$r,data$z )` will produce the same result!

Comment: There is `curve()`. However, this will not work easily here, since you actually have a function FGM: R^3\to R, but only want to plot FGM over the trace of one very particular trajectory in R^3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function of just one variable to `plot`. I guess that you are looking for:

```
    plot(function(x) 1-pnorm(x),0,3)
```

Comment: Even simpler: `curve(1-pnorm(x),0,3)`

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting your data by x, then add the line:

```
data <- data[order(data$x),]
lines(data$x, data$Px, lwd=2)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does produce lines but I'm looking for a solution that plots from the formula rather than the data - I should have made that more clear, I'll edit the Q

Comment: Sorry, that's clear looking back at your question...I saw that you used points so I haistly showed how to make it plot a line.